# How to create custom Adapter with for 3 recycleViews

Tags: kotlin, adapter

**Hello All,
i want to ask if i can add to my 3 recycle Views each recycle view hase interface to optimise my code i tried to add only 1 adapter for the 3 recycle View, as you can see my code below but i find my self stuck with this adapter, any 1 have idea how add custom adapter to adapt 3 recycle View? Thanx.**

class CustomAdapter(private val contexte: Context) :
RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {
private val context: Context = contexte

```
inner class FolderViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

}

inner class PagesViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

}

inner class CorpusViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

}


override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    if (viewType == VIEW_TYPE_CORPUS)
        return CorpusViewHolder(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                .inflate(R.layout.corpus_item_layout, parent, false)
        )
    if (viewType == VIEW_TYPE_FOLDER)
        return FolderViewHolder(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                .inflate(R.layout.folder_item_layout, parent, false)
        )
    return PagesViewHolder(
        LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(
            R.layout.page_item_layout, parent, false
        )
    )
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    TODO("Not yet implemented")
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return 20
}


companion object {
    internal val VIEW_TYPE_CORPUS = 1
    internal val VIEW_TYPE_FOLDER = 2
    internal val VIEW_TYPE_PAGES = 2
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of doing this, I suggest you to use base class that takes layout id and initialize your common adapter with that.

```
open class AdapterItem(val layoutId: Int)
data class Corpus(val id: Int): AdapterItem(id)
```

then init your adapter like
`CustomAdapter<AdapterItem>(...)`

in your adapter, override `getView`

```
@Override
fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View, parent: ViewGroup): View {
     val item = list[position]
     return if(converView != null){
          convertView
     } else {
          LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(item.layoutId, parent, false)
     }
}
```